# Get selected index tabbar controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I'm trying to get the selected index of the tabbarController.

```
let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let tabbarController = application.tabBarController as UITabBarController
let selectedIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

I'm getting this error: `'UITabBarController?' does not have a member named 'selectedIndex'`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`application.tabBarController` is an optional, this means it can be `nil`.
If you are sure it will never be `nil`, do this:

```
var selectedIndex = tabBarController!.selectedIndex
```

Answer (score 4):

you should try this:

```
let application = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let tabbarController = application.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
let selectedIndex = tabbarController.selectedIndex
```

Comment: what about if the TabbarController is not the RootViewController ?